# Making sure no duplicate lines are written to CSV Python

Tags: python, csv

Currently I'm writing rows from a dataset to a CSV file with the following code:

```
with open('Private-Jet-Data.csv', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",")
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Is there a more efficient way to make sure that no row is a duplicate of another in the file without opening up the file first and iterating through the entire file for each row in my `data` list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, its not possible.

You will need to maintain the data somewhere in memory for comparison, and that means you will have to read previous data from the file, and append only the set that is absent from it.

Also note, that in your current code snippet, you are nowhere comparing with entries alerady present in the `.csv` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add "seen" values to a set on the fly:

```
with open('Private-Jet-Data.csv', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",")
    seen = set()
    for row in data:
        if row in seen:
            continue 
        writer.writerow(row)
        seen.add(row)
```

It's more efficient than reading the source file *twice*, but it will still eat some memory if you're working on a large file.

Comment: I don't think that's what OP is asking. He actually has some data (call it dataset_A) in the file, he has generated more data in his script (call it dataset_B), and now wants to print only those values from dataset_B into file which are not there in dataset_A. Basically, `dataset_B - dataset_A.intersection(dataset_B)`

Answer (score 0):

```py
 f.writelines(sorted(set(ls)))
```

**set**!